# what is the c# equivalent of List and Iterator in Java?

Tags: c#, java, iterator

I am manually converting this Java code to C#:

```
private static final List<BigInteger> PRIMES = Arrays.asList(new BigInteger[]
    { new BigInteger("10007"), new BigInteger("10009"),
      new BigInteger("10037"), new BigInteger("10039")});

Iterator<BigInteger> primes = PRIMES.iterator();
```

and this is my code in C#:

```
private static readonly List<BigInteger> PRIMES = new List<BigInteger> {
    10007, 10009,
    10037, 10039 };
IEnumerable<BigInteger> primes = PRIMES.AsEnumerable<BigInteger>();
```

However, I am not sure if my code is correct. I really do not understand about list and iterator in C#.

Please anyone help me to convert the code correctly, any assistance is greatly appericated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Is the code as you have it not working in some way?  It seems to be perfectly valid C# code.  (Though the second variable isn't necessary because the first one is also an `IEnumerable<BigInteger>`.)

Comment: Yes, the code is not working. I have remove AsEnumerable<BigInteger>(); code and now it is working. But, is IEnumerable in C# same with iterator iterator in Java? or, is there a better else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct.  `List<T>` is the C# equivalent of the java `ArrayList<T>`, and `IEnumerable<T>` is more or less the equivalent of the java `Iterator<T>`.  The public API is a bit different, but the end goal is the same.

Note there's no need for the `AsEnumerable` call though.  Since `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` you can just write:

```
IEnumerable<BigInteger> primes = PRIMES;
```

That said, calling `AsEnumerable` isn't really don't anything wrong or costly either.

Comment: Hi Servy, thanks for your help.

So, is the code: IEnumerable<BigInteger> primes = PRIMES; same with Iterator<BigInteger> primes = PRIMES.iterator(); ? I mean, is that the right code to make iterator from PRIMES list in C#?

Comment: @NoeL Well, if you want to be really technical it would be `PRIMES.GetEnumerator()` for a more explicit 1:1 mapping, but in C# you'll mostly be working with `IEnumerable`, which is something that can create an iterator, rather than actually dealing with the iterator itself as you would in java.  So your snippets aren't exactly the same, but those are each the proper way of addressing that same issue in either language.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask too many, but which is the best IEnumerable<BigInteger> primes = PRIMES; or IEnumerator<BigInteger> primes = PRIMES.GetEnumerator(); that equivalent to Iterator<BigInteger> primes = PRIMES.iterator();? If you wish, please tell me the differents. Thanks.

Comment: @NoeL Look up the documentation for the two classes.  It's pretty obvious just looking at the API for the two types what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, but do note that List in c# can be accessed by index so depending on what you're doing you might not need to have the equivalent of an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Java 'List' is an interface, so the .NET equivalent is 'IList', and the .NET equivalent to Java's Iterator is 'IEnumerator', not 'IEnumerable':

```
private static readonly IList<System.Numerics.BigInteger> PRIMES = new System.Numerics.BigInteger[] { 10007, 10009, 10037, 10039 };

internal IEnumerator<System.Numerics.BigInteger> primes = PRIMES.GetEnumerator();
```